# Out of $8$ points, $4$ points on one branch of a hyperbola and $4$ on the other but no $5$ ever in convex position,is it true?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Are any $8$ points, $4$ points on one branch of a hyperbola, $4$ points on the other branch of the same hyperbola always such that no $5$ points are in convex position (form a convex shape)

Comment: is this wrong then? or trivially right? Boring? just a nod? a hrrumph? whatever?

Comment: ok, so flip the idea. what does the fact that there does exist a certain number of points in GP not requiring a convex shape 
of some size say about the non-degenerate curve that has to exist to 'cover' it. 
obviously 5 points don't all have to be convex so 'something' has to exist other than just one curve that 'bends' simply.
In the case of the quadratic it is the two branches of the hyperbola.

Comment: in any set of points in GP that haven't got a convex set of a certain size any algebraic curve that 'fits' through these points
must have a certain amount of 'somethings': branches, points of inflection, singular points... stuff that is not just simple 'bending'
in the same direction. if the curve turns in on itself it must eventually either cross or turn away.
there is a limit to the amount it can 'spiral' and then 'undo' the spiral in one place.

Comment: if not, imagine the reverse. where ccould you place the required number of points on the curve?
the PHP would force you to put more than the required number of points on a section of the curve that would make them convex.

Comment: in fact, the same would apply to the curve being concentric convex hulls as ellipses. a straight line through them would limit this

Comment: Is it related to pigeon hole principle by any chance?

Comment: sry yes. PHP is pigeonhole principle. I tried to express more in another question but too unstructured. One point is that you can have 8 points in GP without a convex pentagon is history of the Happy Endings problem.
In Wikipedia and all other work I've seen, the proof is by example diagram, which is fine, but this seems 'better'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More is true: If we have four points on a hyperbola, three of them on the same branch, and one on the other branch, then these four points do not form a convex quadrangle.

*Proof.* Consider the hyperbola $xy=1$, and assume $P_i=(x_i,y_i)$ $\>(1\leq i\leq3)$ in the first quadrant, with $x_1<x_2<x_3$. The lines $g_{12}=P_1\vee P_2$ and $g_{23}=P_2\vee P_3$ do not intersect the third quadrant. They form a wedge with vertex $P_2$, containing the full third quadrant, hence the full second branch of the hyperbola,  in its interior. It follows that $P_2$ is an interior point of the triangle $\triangle(P_4P_3P_1)$.